# Why training speed does not scale with the batch size?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am surprised that increasing batch size does not increase the total processing speed on a GPU. My measurements:

- batch_size=1:    0.33 sec/step
- batch_size=2:    0.6 sec/step
- batch_size=3:    0.8 sec/step
- batch_size=4:    1.0 sec/step

My expectation was that the time for the step would remain (almost) constant thanks to parallelization on the GPU. However, it almost linearly scales with the batch size. Why? Did I misunderstood something?

I am using [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection), retraining the pre-trained *faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco* model, the predefined batch_size is 1, our GPU (Nvidia 1080 Ti) could handle up to 4 images so I wanted to exploit this to accelerate the training.

Comment: Why is the question down-voted? Please, let me know whats wrong with the question.

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

It's often wrongly mentioned that batch learning is as fast or faster than on-line training. In fact, batch-learning is changing the weights once, the complete set of data (the batch) has been presented to the network. Therefore, the weight update frequency is rather slow. This explains why the processing speed in your measurements acts like you observed.

To get a further understanding for the training techniques, have a look at the 2003 paper [The general inefficiency of batch training for gradient descent learning](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=965272). It deals with the comparison of batch and on-line learning.

### Edit:

Regarding your comment:

I don't think there happens a model or data parallelization on one single GPU. The GPU parallelizes the vector and matrix operations that are involved in the training algorithm, but the batch learning algorithm is still computed as follows:

```
loop maxEpochs times
  for each training item
    compute weights and bias deltas for curr item
    accumulate the deltas
  end for
  adjust weights and bias deltas using accumulated deltas
end loop
```

As you can see, although the weight adjustment is only applied once for the whole batch, the weight and bias deltas still have to be computed for every element in the batch. Therefore there is IMHO no large performance advantage of the batch learning algorithm compared to the on-line learning.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the update of the weights happens less often, i.e., not with every image but with every batch, and that without increasing the learning rate the total convergence could be slower (nevertheless I will have a look at the paper, thanks for reference). However, my question was not about the convergence speed, rather, about the speed the images flow through the network. My expectation was, that the GPU parallelizes the evaluation of each image in the batch, hence the time to process the batch would be independent of the batch size, which is not. Why?

Comment: I edited my answer to (hopefully) answer your question

Comment: If it is so, it changes my (still quite shallow) understanding of how GPU acceleration works, I though that batching it is similar to numpy broadcasting, i.e., that stacking images into 4-D arrays (batches) still involves the same matrix operations, which just happen on larger matrices.

Comment: Question and answer not relevant at all.

Comment: @lukas: I think you are wrong here. Even if its matrix operation, each row-colum multiplication might be happening on one gpu-core. So, full matrix multiplication is divided on as many cores as possible. For one matrix mul, each gpu-core takes some time, and when you add more images, that time increases, do more rows. If at batch size of 4, your gpu is already at full performance capacity, i.e. all cores are running, then increasing batch size is not going to give any advantage. Your added data just sits in gpu memory and is processed when an nvidia dice gets free of previous operation.

Comment: @saurabheights: OK, I totally missed that even with a  single image the convs are already parallelized (and the GPU might be already saturated by that), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recent study of images-per-second for different batch sizes on three different GPUs:

https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/GPU-Memory-Size-and-Deep-Learning-Performance-batch-size-12GB-vs-32GB----1080Ti-vs-Titan-V-vs-GV100-1146/

It validates that using larger batch sizes can improve per-image processing speed on some GPUs due to:

> A larger batch size can also improve performance by reducing the communication overhead caused by moving the training data to the GPU. This causes more compute cycles to run on the card with each iteration.

So, if you are using 1080 Ti then you probably won't see a lot of improvements in terms of images-per-second using larger batch sizes. That is to say, GPU does not really process images in a batch in parallel.